# Using os.system() to convert audio files sample rate

Tags: python, audio, nlp, operating-system

I have started working on an NLP project, and at the start of this, I need to downsample the audio files. To do this I have found one script that can do it automatically, but though I can use it to downsample my audio I'm struggling to understand how it's working.

```
def convert_audio(audio_path, target_path, remove=False):
    """This function sets the audio `audio_path` to:
        - 16000Hz Sampling rate
        - one audio channel ( mono )
            Params:
                audio_path (str): the path of audio wav file you want to convert
                target_path (str): target path to save your new converted wav file
                remove (bool): whether to remove the old file after converting
        Note that this function requires ffmpeg installed in your system."""

    os.system(f"ffmpeg -i {audio_path} -ac 1 -ar 16000 {target_path}")
    # os.system(f"ffmpeg -i {audio_path} -ac 1 {target_path}")
    if remove:
        os.remove(audio_path)
```

this is the code that's giving my trouble, I don't understand how the 4th line from the bottom works, I believe that is the line that resamples the audio files.

The repo this is inside of :
https://github.com/x4nth055/pythoncode-tutorials/

if anyone has information on how this is done I'd love to know, or if there are better ways to downsample audio files! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever used [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)? the docs clearly show the options(maybe need audio expertise to understand)

> -ac[:stream_specifier] channels (input/output,per-stream) Set the number of audio channels. For output streams it is set by default to
> the number of input audio channels. For input streams this option only
> makes sense for audio grabbing devices and raw demuxers and is mapped
> to the corresponding demuxer options.
>
> -ar[:stream_specifier] freq (input/output,per-stream) Set the audio sampling frequency. For output streams it is set by default to the
> frequency of the corresponding input stream. For input streams this
> option only makes sense for audio grabbing devices and raw demuxers
> and is mapped to the corresponding demuxer options.

Explanations for [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell...on Windows, the return
> value is that returned by the system shell after running command. The
> shell is given by the Windows environment variable COMSPEC: it is
> usually cmd.exe, which returns the exit status of the command run; on
> systems using a non-native shell, consult your shell documentation.

for better understanding, suggest print the command

```py
cmd_str = f"ffmpeg -i {audio_path} -ac 1 -ar 16000 {target_path}"
print(cmd_str) # then you can copy paste to cmd/bash and run
os.system(cmd_str)
```